# Python MySQLdb failing to insert

Tags: python, cursor

I'm trying

```
title = "Title here"
url = "http://www.mysite.com/url-goes-here"

cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `videos_justicevids` (`title`, `pageurl`) VALUES (%s, %s)""",(title, url))
```

I'm not getting an error, but it's not inserting into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to commit it.

```
connection.commit()
```